# ViewPager+FragmentPagerAdapter app running slow with one fragment having GridView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have ViewPager in my layout with ViewPager holding three fragments . And i am using gridview for one of the fragment with each grid consisting of images (6 images).When i make transitions between fragment with gridview and fragment with plane text ,the swipe is really very slow .

I have initialised the gridview and layout inflater in OnCreateView() of the fragment which is responding slow .
Should i be using **FragmentStatePagerAdapter** ? But number of fragments i am using is only 3 .How can i make smooth transition between different tabs ?

**code for fragment class with gridview**

```
public class MainTourism extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_tourism, null);
        GridView gridview = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(new TourismImageAdapter(getActivity()));

        return rootView;
    }

}
```

**code for adapter class**

```
public class TourismImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter    {

private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.a,
        R.drawable.b,
        R.drawable.c,
        R.drawable.d};

private Context mContext;
public TourismImageAdapter(Context c){
    mContext = c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(150, 150));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    return imageView;
}

}
```

Comment: Are you manipulating the images on gridview efficiently. Poor image management can cause huge memory issues.

Comment: i have added code for respective classes

Comment: Code seems to be fine, although I am not sure about the images resolution and size. Please go through this wonderful article about image resizing http://blog.jpardogo.com/resize-and-respect/

Comment: ya got it right ..thanks ..one of the image size which i ws using was 304kb bt now i am using smal image size of around 10-20kb ..working fine ..thanks

Comment: just one more q. Is there any way we can set text on lower part of these images programaticaly ? Like we see in gallery

Comment: Better way is to create gridview item xml and the inflate it on adapter getView method and assign image and text data. This will make your UI and code legible and maintainable

Comment: can u provide me with a link to learn .m stil a beginer

Comment: Other than developer.android.com I feel https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki provide good opensource documentation